# Floating points multiplication

Tags: floating-point

I do not understand where to put the point after I multiply two floating point numbers.

Let's say I have those two numbers:

```
float a = 0b11000011000100000100000...
float b = 0b11000011000100000100000...
```

I know that I need to add the exponent and then to multiply the mantissas, but how do I know where to put the point in the end? How I decide where the point should be?

Comment: After multiplying the mantissae you also need to re-normalise and adjust the sum of the exponents accordingly. You don't need to worry about a "decimal point" though - so long as you keep the result mantissa normalised then everything else should just fall into place.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with infinities, zeros, not-a-numbers (NaN) or denormalized (subnormal) values, then the two mantissas (aka mantissae, or significands to use the IEEE 754 term) are fractions in the range [0.5 .. 1.0).  Multiplying two such values yields an answer in the range [0.25 .. 1.0).  Therefore, there is at most 1 bit of adjustment needed to the sum-of-exponents to finally adjust the result, plus a shift to lose the leading zero.